# Harry Potter fan fiction where Hooch gets fired for not even attempting to save Neville during the flying lesson

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Due to failing to stop Neville's broomstick, and thereby almost allowing him to be injured, the Hogwarts broomstick flying Coach known as Hooch is fired for child endangerment, which places Remus Lupin in charge of teaching it, this is a world where the non-magical technology has been made workable, and enhanced by magic, in a version of the story of Harry Potter,  time-shifted 20 years in the future, (from the original time setting of the franchise.)

Comment: In the future could you try and put a bit more effort into your titles to describe the story in a brief overview rather than something incredibly generic?

Comment: Hooch getting fired is incredibly common in crappy political fics so you need to add more details.

Comment: Paragraphs. That is all.

Comment: Is everyone happy now?

Comment: While it's nice of you to reword and clarify your question, please keep the above advice in mind - the previous title was far more helpful than a generic "I don't remember the name of this fanfiction", hence why I edited it back in.

Comment: Maybe break this up into separate sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Vanguards Of Magic.
Chapter 7 The Beast
https://archiveofourown.org/works/4360376/chapters/10666220
Providing a quote would be pointless since it's right in the text and is quite a substantial amount of the chapter.